# How to run Laravel in a Docker container (Nginx, PHP7-fpm) on an EC2 instance

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, redis

I have a new job as a vulnerability and load tester at a company that makes and runs ecommerce sites for apparel companies in Japan.  I don't have a degree in computer science (some first and second year credits) so I'm struggling quite a bit.

First, I gitcloned the repo to my local machine.

Next, are the instructions on our company Bitbucket as follows:

```
install aws-cli
install composer
install npm
```

log in to ecr:
`$(aws ecr get-login --region ap-northeast-1 --no-include-email)`

Get the local environment running with this command:

## If there is no SDK in the local directory, set it using "how to update SDK to the newest version"

## move to php source directory

`cd php/ef`

## edit composer npm

```
composer install
npm install
```

(the contents of package.json package.json.lock have been somewhat edited)
`npm run dev`

```
cd ../..
# set environment variables 
export CUSTOMER_NAME=javag(choose the client)
# docker-compose
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.local.yml up
```

After a short while, php-fpm starts up.  Check `http://localhost:8000/`
You can show changes to files in `php/ds3-base-pre` by reloading.

I apologize for the poor translation from Japanese but basically (from my low knowledge level) I think this ecommerce site is being run in a Docker container in an EC2 instance with Nginx (redis server) as the server and PHP7-fpm as the version of PHP that can be used?  I'm new to web and the only thing I've done so far is to get simple MVC examples running on a local server.

However, my question is, how can I open Laravel inside this container so that all the folders on the left side of my editor like below:

[image: Laravel in Sublime]

I want this so writing Laravel tests would be more organized as I am somewhat accustomed to the folder structure of Laravel and also so I can use the `php artisan` commands to run tests.

I apologize for such a wordy question but I was thrown this task and really I am having to start at Docker for beginner (and beginner level for every technology mentioned above pretty much) so any guidance is welcome.

Edit:

I opened the `/php/ef` directory locally with `subl ef` command and sure enough I have it Laravel style (folders on the side bar).

[image: Locally opened]

Comment: Use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes) to create mounts between the container and host.

Comment: It looks like you have all of the tooling required to run the application installed locally already, and you might see if you can just run it locally and debug it normally (without involving Docker except maybe as a way to get a local database).

Comment: @DavidMaze I just tried opening the `php/ef` directory with sublime and sure enough, I can have it "Laravel style" locally.

Comment: I'm guessing I have to install `redis`, `nginx` and everything else locally since the `.env` files are totally different from the template provided with an empty Laravel project.  Ie. `redis` is in there.  Even opening the project in my `/var/www/html`with my other Laravel projects, I can't `php artisan`